# Publish Power BI report with maximum size

Tags: powerbi, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have Power BI report which is connected to the dynamic 365 to show the report of contact and account but the data set has more then 2 GB of data and I am not able to publish the report.
how can I decrease the size of the data set so that when publish I can refresh and update data set to get the 2 GB of data.

I am not able to publish the report
one thing which I used to take the top 100 rows by using one of the option in the Data Set but when I refresh the data set after publish it get top 100 record

Answer (score 2):

A .pbix file has no size limit, but PowerBI service has a limit of 1GB (for a pro subscription) per dataset, higher-level subscriptions (embedded/premium) have higher limits.

Unless you can upgrade your subscription (which may not be worth it for one report), you have to decrease the report size.
The suggestions are always the same and can be found on [MS website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/import-modeling-data-reduction), I had a look at it and I have nothing to add.

Below the points that you will find on the MS website, in case the link stops working:

- Remove unnecessary columns
- Remove unnecessary rows
- Group by and summarize > pre-aggregate/aggregate data, with the detail you need
- Optimize column data types > chose the right data type for each column
- Preference for custom columns > create custom columns in PowerQuery (M), they have a better compression rate compared to DAX calculated column
- Disable Power Query query load > do not load tables you don't need (support table used for calculations but not needed in the model)
- Disable auto date/time > disables the calendar hierarchy created by PBI for each date in your model
- Switch to Mixed mode > This mode is a mix of import and direct-query, you will find more info online about this. (if you choose this have a look at the *aggregations* functionality)

Comment: I already have removed unnecessary column, rows but still data is more then 2 GB

Comment: Sadly I've nothing else to add, also MS Dynamic does not support direct query mode. The most effective options are to further restrict the range of data and to aggregate some tables (thus reducing the number of rows). If you cannot apply any of the options in the list , then tell whoever manages this that this can't be handled without a higher level subscription.

Comment: "Switch to Mixed mode" I don't have idea of this can you share link or how to get this done?

Comment: it's not supported for MS Dynamic, if you want to check it out anyway you can have a look here: https://radacad.com/composite-model-directquery-and-import-data-combined-evolution-begins-in-power-bi

Comment: Issue is not solve as data is can't be reduced and I am unable to publish report,
is there any way we can create new dataset after publish so that we can't have huge data

Comment: I don't think so, it's a limit of the service itself. If you need a bigger dataset then you will have to upgrade your subscription